# How can I make Matplotlib show all tick labels?

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some time series' and I struggle with the tick labels.
my df looks like this:

```
        Q1-Q5
Date    
2003    -0.183333
2004    -0.195833
2005    0.044167
2006    -0.040000
2007    0.841667
2008    0.251667
2009    -0.913333
2010    -0.471667
2011    0.005833
2012    -0.297500
2013    -0.625833
2014    0.290833
2015    0.059167
2016    0.632500
2017    1.015000
2018    0.258333
2019    0.030000
2020    0.651667
2021    0.255000
```

The code to plot it looks like this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize = (20,20))
df.plot(ax = ax1)
ax1.set_yticks(y_ticks)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 90)
ax1.grid(axis = 'y')
ax1.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
```

The plot however looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKqP6.png

How can I make it thath it shows all years as x ticks?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = pd.read_csv("years_data.txt", sep="    ")

fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize = (20,20))
data.plot(x='Year', y='Q1-Q5', ax = ax1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(data['Year'])
ax1.grid(axis = 'y')
ax1.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
```

The output is:
[image]

I used `set_xticklabels()` function instead of `tick_params()`. I found this tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm). You have to give it the list of tick marks that you desire.

If you want to see only the plot of interest:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
data.plot(x='Year', y='Q1-Q5', ax =ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(data['Year'])
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
```

The output:

[image]

Then I personally like to modify tick marks using the function `plt.setp()`:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
data.plot(x='Year', y='Q1-Q5', ax =ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(data['Year'])
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=-45, ha="left", weight="bold")
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
```

The output is:

[image]